# Any shorter way to post emojis in Discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, string, encoding, discord.py, emoji

When posting Discord emojis in the server, it seems to go much easier if I can somehow copy and paste the emoji directly into my code and then post them in my message:

```
await my_channel.send("Hey this is a  emoji")
```

As opposed to `<:emoji_name:emoji_id>` which is often much longer. I end up running into message-too-long errors when I do it this way because the emoji_id's in particular are looooooong. Is there a shorter way to post lots of custom emojis in a message like the direct copy-paste method without it eating up message space?

Comment: Sadly not, a lot of people have tried that but unfornatelly discord.py doesn't provide us with a shorter version, only the unicodes can be "shorter"

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Is there a definitive list of all the unicode-able emojis?

Comment: All the discord default emojis are unicode, the custom ones aren't

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, custom emotes cannot be shortened.
However, ***Łukasz Kwieciński***'s comment gives a hint.

If you want to use Discord's emotes you can easily transform them for your code. Use the following format:

```py
\:EmoteName:
```

With the `\` the emote will be converted directly to fit your code, you can now copy and paste it perfectly.

If you want a "simpler" way you can have a look at: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html